# How do we calculate such integral $\int _{0}^{4}\:g'(x)\arctan^{2}(2g(x)+3)\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus

> Given \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
> \hline
> g(x) & 1 & \dfrac18 & -\dfrac34 & -\dfrac{13}8 & -\dfrac52\\
> \hline
> \end{array}
>   Integrate $$\int_0^4 g'(x) \arctan^2\left(2g(x)+3\right)\,dx.$$

I try to use method by parts

and assumed $dv =g'(x)$ then $v =g(x)$

$u = \arctan^2(2g(x)+3)$ but stuck on $du$

Comment: Where did you see this problem?  The function $\arctan^2(x)$ doesn't have an antiderivative expressible with elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears in AP Classroom under the BC Content, and is calculator active. The intent is not to do the antiderivative analytically but rather to transform it so that it can be approximated numerically.

Let $u=2g(x)+3$; this makes $du=2g'(x)dx\rightarrow g'(x)dx= \frac12du$. The table of values allows you to change the limits of integration: $x=0\rightarrow u=5$ and $x=4\rightarrow u=-2$.

$$\int_0^4g'(x)\arctan^2(2g(x)+3)dx\rightarrow\frac12\int_5^{-2}\arctan^2(u)du\approx-3.647$$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Try to make the substitution $z = 2g(x) + 3$ and see what happens.

**EDIT**

\begin{align*}
\int\arctan^{2}(z)\mathrm{d}z = z\arctan^{2}(z) - \int\frac{2z\arctan(z)}{1+z^{2}}\mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}

Integrating once again, one has
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{2z\arctan(z)}{1+z^{2}}\mathrm{d}z = \ln(1+z^{2})\arctan(z) - \int\frac{\ln(1+z^{2})}{1+z^{2}}\mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}

Unfortunately, the last integral is not easy to compute. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: arctan^2(z)= 2arctan(z) / ( z^2 +1) , so what next

Comment: @mmm That identity is not true.

Comment: why? , we know that  arctanx = 1/(x^2  +1)

Comment: @mmm so a function is equal to its derivative?

Comment: @mmm I do not know such thing. I know that $\arctan 0=0$, but your formula says $\arctan 0=1$

Comment: @mmm please use MathJax formatting for your equations

Comment: I get $-\frac12\int_{-2}^5\arctan^2(z)\mathrm{d}z$  What now?

Comment: I try to integral arctan^2(z)dz but can't get it